# Reset inherited margin-left for a div

Tags: css

I have a css class which is added in the master page.

```
.mainContent .grid-container {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:0 40px;
    *zoom:1
}
```

This is then inherited by the all other content page. Now I want that in one div of the pages, this is not inherited and the `margin-left` is set as zero. I tried overwriting this class.

But the problem what I am facing is that as`margin-left` is `auto`, while overwriting I can set my margin-left to some value. That will work but I dnt know to while value I should set to `margin-left` while overwriting for that particular div.

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Margins aren't inherited... If they were, all descendent elements of .`grid-container` would be centered.

Comment: They are. All the elements in all the content page are using this.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/margin "Inherited: No". I don't understand what you are after from your description. All I can tell you is that your belief that margins are inherited is incorrect.

Comment: They are not inherited - they are simply following the bounds of the parent element. When you set automatic margins, the element is centered. Therefore, all children elements, when laid out, will fall to the left most border of the bounding parent element. **It is not a bug.**

Comment: I know it is not a bug. How can I fix this if for one element, I dnt want the element to be centered. Or better, suppose I want all the rest elements to be centered and that is taking margin-left and margin-right to be 250px. I dnt want this to happen for only one particular div. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative margins - and it depends on your layout if you are using flexible width (in percentages) or in pixel values. If you are using percentage values, you are in for some mathematical calculations.

In my example (http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/fGmaQ/), the parent container as auto left and right margins with a 75% width. Therefore, to reset its position to the left, you will need to use a left margin of -16.6667%, i.e. `margin-left: -16.66667%;`. Moreover, if you want the element to fill up the full width, you will need to redeclare the width, too.

Otherwise, you might have to rely on JS to dynamically calculate the require left margins.

Answer (score 0):

Use smth like:

```
margin-left: -100px;
```

if you now the precise value, elsewhere, you have to organize your styles in a different way, to have both full-width containers and fixed-width containers.

Comment: I first tried smthg like ths. So suppose according to the resolution, I need margin-left:250px; but in some other resolution I need margin-left:-300px; So, I dnt know how to find this precise value and modify margin-left and margin-right value according to this value. Any examples would help.

Comment: this is the most usable page design, but if you really want to go with minus margin you should use window.width via js or jquery to catch the current window size, and the calculate minus margin